# Remove all record in CoreData Entity

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, save, swiftui

I am trying to implement CoreData in my app with SwiftUI.

I have create the entity Aeroporti with 2 attributes `icaoAPT` and `iataAPT`

My app downloads some data from a Firebase database and save the data locally for offline usage.

I managed to saved all data in the entity Aeroporti but now I want to create a function to delete all data stored, before the user is going to download the updated data again.

I manage to delete the data at single index directly in the contentView with the func `cancella()`.

But now I am facing a problem with the func delate all in the DataManager.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dm : DataManager
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: Aeroporti.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Aeroporti.iataAPT, ascending: true)]) var aeroport : FetchedResults<Aeroporti> // crea la variabile che contiene le ricette
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
              HStack{
                
                Button(action: {
                    DataManager.shared.downloadData(dbCore: self.managedObjectContext)
                }) {
                    Text("save from manager")
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    DataManager.shared.delateALL(dbCore: self.managedObjectContext)
                }) {
                    Text("del all")
                }
                
                
            }
        List{
          
            ForEach(aeroport, id: \.self) { apt in
                VStack{
                Text(apt.iataAPT ?? "sconosciuto")
                Text(apt.icaoAPT ?? "sconosciuto")
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: cancella)
        }
        
    }
    
    }
    // this delate at single index
    func cancella(at offset : IndexSet) { //1 ricevo indice ricetta , indexset è un array di indici
           
           for index in offset { // 2 ciclo dentro l'array offset con dentro gli indici
              let apt = aeroport[index] // 3 tiro furoi la ricetta a quel indice
               
               managedObjectContext.delete(apt) // 7 cancella alla fine la ricetta
           }
           do { // 8 salvo
               try self.managedObjectContext.save()
              
              
           } catch {
               debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
           }
       }
}
```

I want to delate all record in the entity Aeroporti, I have try to write this, but of course I'm stuck:

```
class DataManager:  ObservableObject {
    
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    static let shared = DataManager()
    

    
    // get data from Firestore and Save locally
    func downloadData(dbCore: NSManagedObjectContext ) {
    
            db.collection("VHHH").document("VHHHid").getDocument { (document, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    if document != nil && document!.exists  {
    
                        let data = document!.data()

    
                        let icaoAPT = data?["icaoAPT"] ?? "empty"
                        let iataAPT = data?["iataAPT"] ?? "empty"
    
                        let aeroporto = Aeroporti(context: dbCore)
                        aeroporto.icaoAPT = icaoAPT as? String
                        aeroporto.iataAPT = iataAPT as? String
    
                        debugPrint(aeroporto.iataAPT!)
                        
                        do {
                            try dbCore.save()
                            print("Saved Data")
                        } catch {
                            
                            let nserror = error as NSError
                            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    

    // test delate all...NOT WORKING
    func delateALL(dbCore: NSManagedObjectContext, vett: FetchedResults<NSFetchRequestResult>){
 
//        let req = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Aeroporti")
        
         // 3 tiro furoi la ricetta a quel indice
        for data in vett {
          let data1 = vett[0]
//            dbCore.delete(data1)
        }
    }

    // delate all but not update
//    func delateALL2(dbCore: NSManagedObjectContext){
//        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Aeroporti")
//        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
//
//
//        do {
//            try dbCore.execute(deleteRequest)
//            debugPrint("canx all")
//
//            do {
//                try dbCore.save()
//                print("Saved Data")
//            } catch {
//
//                let nserror = error as NSError
//                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
//            }
//
//        } catch let error as NSError {
//            debugPrint(error)
//        }
//
//    }

}
```

thanks for the helping me

Answer (score 2):

```
func deleteRecords() {
        // References to context
        let context = App.persistency.container.viewContext

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Aeroporti")
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

        do {
            try context.persistentStoreCoordinator?.execute(deleteRequest, with: context)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Fetch failed. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

In order to update your UI, you could make something like:

1. Create an `@State private var airportCount: Int?`
2. In your `body content`, add an `onAppear(_:)` modifier, and add to airportCount the correct airport total count you have in your DB once the view is loaded.
3. When you invoke the method `deleteRecords()`, be sure to update your `airportCount` variable with the new number (0), and your view will be updated.

And that's it. The view should reload.

Comment: it works, but the contentView not updated immediately.. it empty only after restart the app

Comment: Ohh, okay, I edit my answer in order to update also the UI. There are a lot of ways to achieve the view update, but this is the simpler.